# Should I pass the broadcast variable or broadcast.value() into my RDD[custom object]?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, broadcast

I have some fairly large lists that I need to access within each of the objects that comprise my RDD. So after I broadcast these lists, should I be passing in the broadcast variable or the broadcast.value() into each of the objects? I don't want the list to be replicated for each object, but for each object to be able to use the lists. My code looks something like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, number, broadcasted)
        self.NUMBER = number
        self.BROADCASTED = broadcasted

broadcasted_list = sc.broadcast([a, b, c, ...])
```

so should I create the RDD as

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda x: foo(x, broadcasted_list))
```

or

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda x: foo(x, broadcasted_list.value()))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure it out? Did my solution work for you?

Comment: yup thanks! I went with just passing in the broadcast variable and calling the value on the reference to the object when I needed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want `self.BROADCASTED` to contain. I'm assuming you've simplified your method `foo` for this example, but because of that it's not clear what the purpose of `foo` is.

If you want it to contain `[a,b,c,..]`, then do `broadcasted_list.value()`.

If you want that variable to contain a reference to a broadcasted object, pass in `broadcasted_list`.

Assuming you need the values within the list to perform further calculations, you would want to use `broadcasted_list.value()`. I think you'll find that if you pass in `broadcasted_list` you will end up with merely a reference to an object, something that looks like this: `<pyspark.broadcast.Broadcast object at 0x1f36f50>`.